# Using extensions with Google Chrome Selenium driver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to add my extensions like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
executable_path = "C:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('C:/Users/Wilson/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Wilson/Dropbox/xxx.py", line 77, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__
    desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\options.py", line 140, in to_capabilities
    chrome_options["extensions"] = self.extensions
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\options.py", line 76, in extensions
    file_ = open(ext, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Wilson/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions'
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
    chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chop.add_argument('load-extension=path/to/extension')
```

Try this with the extension that you want and see if it is still giving you the same error

this is syntax for python

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and wasn't able to get `add_extension` working. Instead, we can use the `add_argument` function. My folder structure is as follows:

```
ProjectRoot
|-- extension
|   |-- manifest.json
    |-- popup.html
|   `-- other extension files etc...
`-- start.py
```

And here's my `start.py`:

```
import inspect, os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
EXTENSION_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'extension')

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(
    'load-extension={0}'.format(EXTENSION_ROOT)
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://www.google.co.uk')
```

Comment: You have my utmost respect and appreciation.

Comment: Glad this has helped someone 6 years on :)