# How to add chrome extension to selenium without PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting this error, error about Permision WHY :

```
.....
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'my_path\\1.0.5_0'
```

When running this :

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


executable_path = "chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
path = r'my_path\hcdnbmbdfhhfjejboimdelpfjielfnde\1.0.5_0'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension(path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using extensions with Google Chrome Selenium driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130671/using-extensions-with-google-chrome-selenium-driver)

Comment: error shows `my_path\\1.0.5_0'` but in code you show `r'my_path\hcdnbmbdfhhfjejboimdelpfjielfnde\1.0.5_0'` - maybe you run different code.

Comment: thank you I solved the problem my self, the issue was I adding extension folder (this is the error). Instead I had to add .crx file

Answer (score 1):

```
# path have to be to .crx file of extension NOT EXTENSION FOLDER
# you have to convert all extension folder to .crx (you can do it online just google it)

path = r'my_path\Your_Extension.crx'

# This Solved The Problem
```